# How to use QFileSelector in Qt Creator

Tags: qt, qml, qt-creator

I want to show 2 different background images on PC and Android platform using `QFileSelector` in Qt 5.3.2.

It may be easy for you, but I really need to understand about it.

So awesome to be helped.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Have you read [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qfileselector.html)? What is your problem?